Unable to access routes after adding them in protected routes with Outlet
I am trying to created protected routes in react-router-dom v6. But once placing the nested routes I'm unable to access them. Getting error No routes matched location "/places/new"
These routes are working fine explicitly if removed from <PrivateRoutes>.
I have written the routes as below :
<AuthContext.Provider value={{isLogin : isLogin, login : login, logout : logout}}>
      <Router>
        <main>
        <MainNavigation></MainNavigation>
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Users></Users>} exact></Route>
              <Route path="/:userId/places" element={<UserPlaces/>}></Route>
              <Route path="places/" element={<PrivateRoutes isAuthenticated={isLogin}>
                <Route path="new" element={<NewPlace></NewPlace>}></Route>
                <Route path=":placeId" element={<UpdatePlace></UpdatePlace>}></Route>
              </PrivateRoutes>}>
              </Route>
              <Route path="/auth" element={<Authenticate></Authenticate>}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </main>
      </Router>
    </AuthContext.Provider>

PrivateRoutes is defined as below :
const PrivateRoutes = ({isAuthenticated, children}) => {
    const navigate = useNavigate()
    useEffect(() => {
        if(!isAuthenticated) {
            navigate('/auth')
        }  
    }, [isAuthenticated, navigate]);
    return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet></Outlet> : null
}


Nested routes must be children of another route. Try this
<AuthContext.Provider value={{ isLogin: isLogin, login: login, logout: logout }}>
    <Router>
        <main>
            <MainNavigation></MainNavigation>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Users></Users>} exact></Route>
                <Route path="/:userId/places" element={<UserPlaces />}></Route>
                <Route path="places/" element={<PrivateRoutes isAuthenticated={isLogin}/>}>
                    <Route path="new" element={<NewPlace></NewPlace>}></Route>
                    <Route path=":placeId" element={<UpdatePlace></UpdatePlace>}></Route>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/auth" element={<Authenticate></Authenticate>}></Route>
            </Routes>
        </main>
    </Router>
</AuthContext.Provider>


+1 for your route configuration. This is working for me. By the we should keep using useEffect as it will redirect back to auth page once user gets logged out.

Okay, i didn't know that. I have edited the answer now you can accept that please :)
